# What's this exact quote from Lost Eden?

Tags: lost-eden

I don't know if anyone remembers this beautiful adventure game from the 90s:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lost_Eden

If so, can you tell me this quote the archivist dinosaur says to Adam, the main character, when talking about the frescoes that tell of a time when humans built edifices with the help of dinosaurs?

What I remember of the quote is: "Graa is dead. But the..."

It's a fantastic game with a great script and I'd love to know how the quote ends.

Comment: I'll just point out that according to the Wiki page you provided, I suspect it's not "Graah", but "Graa". This doesn't help with any google searches, however.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this the quote you're looking for:

> "Graa is dead. But, his secret lies
>   with his remains, in the Crypt of
>   Abandon. You have come of age Adam.
>   You must do what your father has never
>   been willing to do.
>
> Before I depart
>   this world, I want to give you this
>   shell. It is an object of power. With
>   it you can call out to me in the
>   Valley of Mists. If it is in my power
>   to help you, I will.
>
> It is time, the ancestors beckon me. Farewell children."

This dialogue is spoken near the beginning of the game by Dina's father, Tau, while explaining to Adam the importance of his coming of age.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you (actually I didn't even know the game before ;)), but if you still remember at which point in the game it was, it may be a good way to find out by watching a walkthrough on youtube:

[Lost Eden Walkthrough](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=lost%20eden%20walkthrough&aq=f)

Maybe also looking at some walkthroughs my help you finding the part of the game when this happened, so it is easier to find the part on the youtube walkthrough.

[Gamefaqs walkthrough](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/565039-lost-eden/faqs)

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't accept that as an answer. Isn't anyone out there with the game that can check it out? This game is quite the cult classic.

Comment: Yes I know thats no exact answer, its more an Howto how I do it if I am looking for something in an old classic ;) And there was no answer for weeks. So I'd gave it a try. If nobody knows the answer, that would at least be the fastest way to find out ;)

Comment: @Solivagant, this really is an answer IMO.  Are you not able to better pin down the exact time when the quote occurs?

Comment: I'm sorry, I could not accept it because it was not an answer, according to the rules of the bounty I set. I wanted an answer, not a pathway, however I hope I picqued the interest in this fantastic game, that is well due an update.